# how I use MFSideMenu?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, mfslidemenu

I'm trying to create a MFSideMenu however I never used it and do not know what it missing. Can anyone write a short tutorial on how to finalize it?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                    containerWithCenterViewController:centerViewController
                                                    leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController
                                                    rightMenuViewController:rightMenuViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = container;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: The [GitHub](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu) page has all the necessary documentation you need to implement it, with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AppDelegate.h

```
#import "MFSideMenuContainerViewController.h"
```

In AppDelegate.m

```
MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationController"];  //I have instantiated using storyboard id. 
    UIViewController *leftSideMenuViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"sideMenuViewController"];   //I have instantiated using storyboard id. 

    [container setLeftMenuViewController:leftSideMenuViewController];
    [container setCenterViewController:navigationController];
```

In Your controller.m add:

```
- (IBAction)menuPressed:(id)sender
{
     [self.menuContainerViewController toggleLeftSideMenuCompletion:nil];
}

- (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)menuContainerViewController
 {
 return  (MFSideMenuContainerViewController*)self.navigationController.parentViewController;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this code into your AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


    // init center, left, and right view controllers

    MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                    containerWithCenterViewController:centerViewController]
leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController
rightMenuViewController:rightMenuViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = container;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];



    return YES;
}
```

Comment: what is the centerViewController??

Comment: centerViewController is any view controller that you want to be in the center. For example: launch Facebook app. Your news feed is a CenterViewController. Tap on the button on the right side of navigation bar - your friends list is displayed - that is a rightViewController.